# How to find the variance of an independent variable across the big number of linear regression equations?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, variance, estimation

### Question

I have a big number of linear regression equations with known dependent variables and coefficients, in a form of:

`T = Aa + Bb + Cc + Dd`

where `T` - known dependent variable; `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` - known coefficients;

`a`, `b`, `c`, `d` - are random variables. Each of them is normally distributed across all equations. Their distribution characteristics (mean and variance) is different between each other, but the same across other equations.

How to find the variance of each variable's distribution across all equations?

### Real world example

`T` - total time spent on a task

`A`, `B`, `C`, `D` - number of different steps in a task (e.g. "checked 2 emails", "answered 4 calls", "walked 0 kilometers")

Data:

```
T,A,B,C,D
8.01,0,1,2,0
7.94,4,2,0,0
12.06,0,4,0,1
8.08,1,2,1,0
8.03,6,1,0,0
12.09,0,1,2,1
7.94,4,2,0,0
8.06,0,4,0,0
15.91,1,2,1,2
8.03,6,1,0,0
8.01,0,1,2,0
7.94,4,2,0,0
11.97,0,4,0,1
8.08,1,2,1,0
8.03,6,1,0,0
8.01,0,1,2,0
7.94,4,2,0,0
20.01,0,4,0,3
8.01,1,2,1,0
8.03,6,1,0,0
12.07,0,1,2,1
7.94,4,2,0,0
8.06,0,4,0,0
8.08,1,2,1,0
8.03,4,2,0,0
```

We need to answer the question whether our definition of steps (calls/emails/kilometers/...) is good or not. It's good when it's stable and predictable (variance is low) across any task. "Kilometers" step is much better then "calls", because it's always takes 10-15 minutes per 1 kilometer, while calls can take from 1 second to 1 hour per 1 call easily.

### What I've tried

I tried a `LINEST` spreadsheet function, and I was able to get an average time for each step. For the data above, it's about `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` for `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` respectively.

But the average time for a step (e.g. 12.5min for "kilometers", and 30minutes for "calls") doesn't answer the question, if it's a "good" step or not. Somehow I need to understand how value is changing across different tasks.

Comment: What do you mean by "across all equations"? And in the end you write that you need to understand how the value changes across different tasks but the data you provide it seems to me they refer only to one task.

Comment: Each row is a task and a linear equation in a form of T = Aa + Bb + Cc + Dd where A,B,C,D -coefficients (number of different steps), a,b,c,d - independent variables (time spent on those steps. T - dependent variable, total time spent on task.

Time spent on same step may be different in different tasks, but I assume that it is normally distributed across all tasks (equations). I need to find variance of each step.